# sslv3 alert handshake error

Tags: php, curl

So, I've seen quite a bit of posts about this error, but none of them has been able to fix it.

I wanted to try out the [vgy.me api](https://vgy.me/api) and followed the example there with my PHP 7.0.7 setup. Problem is, I can't get it to work and it only results in
`error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`
I found an answer saying that I should update my cURL version, since I was running 7.37.0. I tried downloading and compiling 7.54.0 and now `curl --version` outputs the new version, but phpinfo still says 7.37.0 and the error still shows up. I tried restarting the web server, but it still says the old version. Am I missing something?

Running OpenSUSE Leap

Thanks :)